# What is the correct way to upgrade a Lazarus project?

Tags: formatting, lazarus

Some months ago I installed Lazarus 0.9.28 + FPC 2.2.4 to work on a new project. Some time after it I ran into some bugs related with image loading on a TImage. After googling a bit I found some information pointing to the fact that the bugs I was facing were already solved in a later version of FPC (can't remember the link now).

So I decided to download and install a newer version. This was around January and the latest stable version was not released yet, so I choose to install the snapshot Lazarus 0.9.31-29128 +  FPC 2.4.2-2011-01-20. I opened my project with the new IDE and compiled it.

Luckily the bugs I faced were gone, but I have run into an IDE (?) one. After the upgrade, when I am on the code tab of some of my forms I do not see the code formatted. Instead I only see plain text, like this:

[image: wrong look]

But on some forms I see the code formatted correctly, like this:

[image: right look]

Anyone has run into this before? If yes, could you solve it and how? Or can anyone tell me what the correct way to upgrade a Lazarus project between versions is?

It is more of a nuisance than a real problem but still I would like to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I noticed that in the forms where the code shows correctly highlighted the LCLVersion in the .lfm file is 0.9.28.2, while in the forms where the code shows like plain text that property in the .lfm file is 0.9.31. Could have something to do with the problem? I tried changing the value but it did not change anything.

Thanks in advance and best regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is actually causing your problem, but Lazarus keeps a set of settings in application local. ($user\AppData\Local\lazarus on my vista).

This config dir is not erased upon deinstallation, and the new installation will reuse this.

In case of strange problems, remove the config dir, and let the current installation generate a new one.

Comment: That may have been the problem, but I am not sure. I remember doing what you suggest after installing the 0.9.31 snapshot and having a problem with some components installation, but not after facing the IDE problem. I will try it again. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @Marco, it did not work and provoked a problem with the installation of the Zeos components, so I had to restore the folder. Could it be some problem with the .lpr or some other project file? Anyway, +1 since I think what you posted is something everyone using Lazarus should know. :)

Comment: If the installation of the zeos components was in the old installation, and not repeated in the new, that was exactly the purpose. Assume that Lazarus doesn't upgrade, and that you need to rebuild your environment with a new release.

Comment: thx for the info. Anyway, by "problem with the .lpr or some other project file" I meant the formatting problem, not the Zeos installation problem. My fault, since what I wrote was misleading. Sorry for that.

Comment: Well, syntax highlighter settings are also in those files, and letting the new version cleanly initialized itself could be a smart thing to do

Comment: Uninstalled Lazarus, removed the config file and the Lazarus directory and installed Lazarus again. No luck, still have the syntax highlighting problem. Anyway, I noticed something different between the forms that show correctly and the ones that do not. Please check the edited question.